# Blank configuration screen

Tags: configuration

Since I've upgraded to CE 1.8.1.0 I have been getting the following error message:
"Warning tax discount configuration might result in different discounts than a customer might expect . Please see source for more details.Click here to go to Tax configuration and change your settings."

When I attempt to go to my configuration I get a blank screen.

What happened?

Comment: Check ur log file

Comment: You can temporarily adjust your index.php file to enable `setIsDeveloperMode` (by comment the if statement) and enable the `ini_set` underneath it regarding `display_errors`. Then try your save action again. If there is an error, it should be displayed then.

Comment: Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Comment: Plus: here you get more informaiton on your tax configuration problem: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc